# C shell printing out the current CPU time?

Tags: shell, time, csh

Simple question... I just want to print out the CPU time at various places in my script to see what's taking so long to execute.

Thanks.

Comment: Just to be clear: Do you want the CPU time or wall-clock time?

Comment: CPU time if possible, if not I'll settle for hours/minutes/seconds timestamp since what I'm testing takes a few hours to run anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

date +%s.%N

Should (did not test) print out Unix time on seconds dot nanoseconds (of course not really that accurate).

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question literally,

You'll need to consult your system man page for `ps` to see what options you have to pass in to see CPU time. It likely will display in one of the default views. Then you'll need to run a parallel process to execute your `ps .... cmd.`, in a loop, with a something like `sleep 1`. OR you'll need run your c-shell launched processes in the background with the '&' char at the end of a cmd, and then construct loops with `ps ... ; sleep 1;` to see the status.

BUT.. Why not just add add messages before and after each segment of your script, ie.

```
echo "P1 start : current time is `date`"
longrunningProcess1
echo "P1 end : current time is `date`"

echo "P2 start : current time is `date`"
longrunningProcess2
echo "P2 end : current time is `date`"
```

IHTH